# How to split string without white space?

Tags: c#, string, split, character

I have a simple question on C#, basically I want to split a string (without white space) into word based on the upper case character.

Let say I have a string "MenInBlack", I want to split it into: "Men","In" and "Black"

I have tried `Regex.Split` but not as per my objective, the code sample as below:

```
string[] word = Regex.Split(a, @"[A-Z]",RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

Seem like Split method will exclude the split condition, and I get only "en", "n" and "lack".

Any idea how to solve the above?

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 3):

Don't split, search. Splitting means you have a delimiter, i.e. something not part of the token separating the tokens from one another.

Just search for `[A-Z][a-z]+`

```
var regex = new Regex(@"([A-Z][a-z]*)");
var matches = regex.Matches(searchString);
```

Comment: I think splitting is possible with look ahead.

Comment: Look aheads will lower your performance, though. I'm honestly unsure whether or not semantically the OP is doing a search or split. All roads lead to Rome, perhaps?

Comment: Agree about the performance part. But if it's once in a while then it should not cause problem. +1 to answer.

Comment: Just a minor nitpick. Shouldn't that be: @"([A-Z][a-z]*)"?

Comment: @IlianPinzon Indeed. It was originally `+`, and I changed it to allow for single character tokens to `?` instead of `*`. I guess it means I should get to bed (3AM). Thanks.